# Convert Categorical Features (Enum) in H2o to Boolean

Tags: python, pandas, enums, boolean, h2o

in my Pandas Dataframe I have loads of boolean Features (`True/False`). Pandas correctly represents them as `bool` if I do `df.dtypes`. If I pass my data frame to h2o (`h2o.H2OFrame(df)`) the boolean features are represented as `enum`. So they are interpreted as categorical features with 2 categories.

Is there a way to change the type of the features from `enum` to `bool`? In Pandas I can use `df.astype('bool')`, is there an equivalent in H2o?

One idea was to encode `True/False` to their numeric representation (`1/0`) before converting `df` to a H2o-Frame. But H2o now recognises this as `int64`.

Thanks in Advance for help!

Answer (score 4):

The enum type is used for categorical variables with two or more categories. So it includes boolean. I.e. there is no distinct bool category in H2O, and there is nothing you need to fix here.

By the way, if you have a lot of boolean features because you have manually done one-hot encoding, don't do that. Instead give H2O the original (multi-level categorical) data, and it will do one-hot encoding when needed, behind the scenes. This is better because for algorithms like decision trees) they can use multi-level categorical data directly, so it will be more efficient.

See http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/categorical_encoding.html for some alternatives you can try. The missing category is added for when that column is missing in production.

(But "What happens when you try to predict on a categorical level not seen during training?" at http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/deep-learning.html#faq does not seem to describe the behaviour you see?)

Also see http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/use_all_factor_levels.html (I cannot work out from that description if you want it to be true or false, so try both ways!)

UPDATE: set `use_all_factor_levels = F` and it will only have one input neuron (plus the NA one) for each boolean input, instead of two. If your categorical inputs are almost all boolean types I'd recommend setting this. If your categorical inputs mostly have quite a lot levels I wouldn't (because, overall, it won't make much difference in the number of input neurons, but it might make the network easier to train).

**WHY MISSING(NA)?**

If I have a boolean input, e.g. "isBig", there will be 3 input neurons created for it. If you look at `varimp()` you can see there are named:

```
isBig.1
isBig.0
isBig.missing(NA)
```

Imagine you now put it into production, and the user does not give a value (or gives an NA, or gives an illegal value such as "2") for the isBig input. This is when the NA input neuron gets fired, to signify that we don't know if it is big or not.

To be honest, I think this cannot be any more useful than firing both the .0 and the .1 neurons, or firing neither of them. But if you are using `use_all_factor_levels=F` then it *is* useful. Otherwise all NA data gets treated as "not-big" rather than "could be big or not-big".

Comment: thanks for your answer. I was just wondering, because my h2o deep learning model (one-hot-encoding) is generating dummy-features for bool-Features and there is also one Feature for the 'Missing'-Category added, although I do not have any missing values left in my data frame. My thought was that this comes from wrong interpreting bool as enum. Why does the DeepLearning Model add Features for the 'Missing'-Category?

Comment: But there is a 'Missing(NA)'-Category added for a Boolean Feature that has not any missing Values. The Feature is not missing in training or test data. Why is this happening? I just want to understand and be clear what(and why) features are in my model in the end.

Comment: @dnks23 I added a couple of sections to my answer.